# How can I learn regex for ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I learn regular expressions for ruby? (for a dummy)

Comment: Learn general regexes, and then just check for api in Ruby.

Answer (score 7):

http://www.rubular.com/ is a great tool when working with regular expressions in Ruby as it visualizes the results instantly.

Answer (score 4):

The website [www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) contains a lot of information on regular expressions in many different programming languages, including Ruby.

Comment: +1 that site is a great resource. 

In addition to using that site, I would also strongly recommend reading a book on regex.

Also, I use [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) to test regex expressions.

Comment: Another good book is the Regular Expressions Cookbook: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520694/

Answer (score 1):

I personally find the book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) by Jeffrey Friedl the best book for diving into regular expressions. Ruby's regular expressions are pretty much PCRE, but Ruby 1.9 also supports Oniguruma. It doesn't matter, know PCRE and you're good. The book will get you covered.

Answer (score 0):

Start from [Ruby basic tutorial](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could buy a book.

[This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689) is a great RegEx book - excellent reviews and has its examples in Ruby.

[This](http://www.rubular.com/) is another great resource for testing your RegExs as you write them - but there is various software out there that can help you too ([here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) and [here](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm))

Answer (score 0):

You can also test your Regexp at http://www.rubyxp.com/

As peku mentions, instant visualization really helps.